# Elasticsearch sort by field existance

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort my ES search result by field existance, 
Say I got field "price" and want all results that have price be on top and all without it be on bottom. 
I know you can just do a simple sort and add "missing": "_last" e.g:

> {"sort" : [{'price': {'missing': '_last', 'order': 'asc'}}]}

but in this case results will also be sorted by price and I don't want it.

Is there a way to do it without script?

Comment: could you post the query you have tried ?

Comment: @keety I've added example of filter with "missing" param to description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to achieve this.
It would  involve using  [weight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight) to reduce the score of documents which do not contain the particular field .

Example :

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "weight": 0.5,
               "filter": {
                  "missing": {
                     "field": "price"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This above would cause documents with field price to show higher up.

Comment: thanks, but in terms of speed is it the same as script?

Comment: since we are using the builtin functions for function score my guess is it is faster than script however  i have not compared with the equivalent script. implementation.